# Regex for extracting filename from path

Tags: regex

I need to extract just the filename (no file extension) from the following path....

`\\my-local-server\path\to\this_file may_contain-any&character.pdf`

I've tried several things, most based off of something like http://regexr.com?302m5 but can't quite get there

Comment: Which language? Some languages have a method to parse URIs in their standard library.

Comment: I'm skeptical a regex would be faster than getting the index of the last path separator, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This question is vague as it only contains one example of path and filename structure. Regex is used to match and/or capture different structures which have some similarity.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
^\\(.+\\)*(.+)\.(.+)$
```

This regex has been tested on these two examples:

\var\www\www.example.com\index.php 
\index.php

First block "(.+\)*" matches directory path. 
Second block "(.+)" matches file name without extension. 
Third block "(.+)$" matches extension.

Comment: This is a general approach with some issues. This fails on filenames without an extension, which are not uncommon on *NIX systems. Additionally, the question indicated double leading backslash, so I'd possibly add another escaped backslash outside the capture groups. No mention was made of capturing the path or the extension, so it could be simplified.

Comment: Also fails if the file has no path.

Answer (score 20):

This will get the filename but will also get the dot. You might want to truncate the last digit from it in your code.

```
[\w-]+\.
```

**Update**

@Geoman if you have spaces in file name then use the modified pattern below

```
[ \w-]+\.      (space added in brackets)
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/9FM53SI7dQ)

Comment: fails: `c:\fakepath\some filename with spaces.png`

Comment: Fails if path contains folder names with dots in them.

Comment: Requirement is filename without extension. You can post a separate question for you needs

Comment: This worked for related question of mine (file name with extension, but none of the directories -- just add `[\w-]*$` after `\.` -- this also removes issue with having a dot in a folder name).

Comment: Also fails if filename does not have an extension.

Answer (score 16):

This is just a slight variation on @hmd's so you don't have to truncate the `.`

```
[ \w-]+?(?=\.)
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/G1nqkuFryF)

Really, thanks goes to @hmd. I've only slightly improved on it.

Comment: Fails if path contains a dot or if filename does not have an extension or if there is no path.

Answer (score 10):

I use `@"[^\\]+$"`
That gives the filename including the extension.

Comment: I can't believe this was answered 3 hrs ago, thanks a lot! I had to extract the file name with no extension and therefore no dot in the end from S3 resource path. Just had to replace \\ with \/ to work with S3 path, works like a charm!

Comment: Is this correct? Shouldn't be `[^\/]+$`?

Comment: @fabianoLothor - If the url has forward slashes then it's your way. If it's backslashes then my way. The question was backslashes.

Answer (score 9):

Try [this](http://regexr.com?302mq):

```
[^\\]+(?=\.pdf$)
```

It matches everything except back-slash followed by `.pdf` at the end of the string.

You can also (and maybe it's even better) take the part you want into the capturing group like that:

```
([^\\]+)\.pdf$
```

But how you refer to this group (the part in parenthesis) depends on the language or regexp flavor you're using. In most cases it'll be smth like `$1`, or `\1`, or the library will provide some method for getting capturing group by its number after regexp match.

Comment: Should it be more like: `[^\\](.+)\.pdf$`

Comment: @macduff the question is also the path or just the filename..?

Comment: I understood it to be the filename, but not the extension or path, sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @KL-7 Thanks, but I don't want the .pdf.  I tried using `[^\\]+[^.pdf]$` and that concept didn't work

Comment: This is a good answer if extension must be _.pdf._ and the path is _variable_. It matches paths with dots and files with no path. I think that it's probably better to explicitly specify the path, though.

Comment: @macduff how about this `.*\/(.+)$`

Comment: `[^\\^\/]+(?=\.ini$)` will handles both type of slashes

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this regex to replace the filename of the file with `index`. It matches a contiguous string of characters that doesn't contain a slash and is followed by a `.` and a string of word characters at the end of the string. It will retrieve the filename including spaces and dots but will ignore the full file extension.

```js
const regex = /[^\\/]+?(?=\.\w+$)/

console.log('/path/to/file.png'.match(regex))
console.log('/path/to/video.webm'.match(regex))
console.log('/path/to/weird.file.gif'.match(regex))
console.log('/path with/spaces/and file.with.spaces'.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for a windows absolute path (and relative path) javascript regular expression in javascript for files:

```
var path = "c:\\my-long\\path_directory\\file.html";


((/(\w?\:?\\?[\w\-_\\]*\\+)([\w-_]+)(\.[\w-_]+)/gi).exec(path);
```

Output is:

```
[
"c:\my-long\path_directory\file.html", 
"c:\my-long\path_directory\", 
"file", 
".html"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

[<kbd>TEST</kbd>](https://regexr.com/7pt3p) `^(.*[\\\/])?(\.*.*?)(\.[^.]+?|)$` (improved version)

[<kbd>TEST</kbd>](https://regexr.com/4s1jc) `^(.*[\\\/])?(.*?)(\.[^.]*?|)$` (old version)

example:

```
/^(.*[\\\/])?(\.*.*?)(\.[^.]+?|)$/.exec("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\foo.ext1.ext")
```

result:

```
0: "C:\folder1\folder2\foo.ext1.ext"
1: "C:\folder1\folder2\"
2: "foo.ext1"
3: ".ext"
```

the `$1` capture group is the folder
the `$2` capture group is the name without extension
the `$3` capture group is the extension (only the last)

improved version based on @Therkel's comments:

- if the filename starts with dot(s), it will be part of the name, not part of the extension (`.gitignore` => file name only, no extension)
- also, if the path ends with a dot, it will be part of the filename and will not have an extension (`..its-all-name..` => just filename, no extension)

```js
const rx = /^(.*[\\\/])?(\.*.*?)(\.[^.]+?|)$/;


const testItems = [
    // has extension
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\foo.ext", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "foo", ".ext"],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\foo.ext1.ext", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "foo.ext1", ".ext"],
    ["name.ext", undefined, "name", ".ext"],
    ["/dir1/dir2/foo.ext", "/dir1/dir2/", "foo", ".ext"],
    ["C:\\special$chars\\f2\\f [oo].ext1.e-x-t", "C:\\special$chars\\f2\\", "f [oo].ext1", ".e-x-t"],
    [".only name leading period .name.ext", undefined, ".only name leading period .name", ".ext"],
    ["\\d.i.r\\d.i.r2/.name- with extension.R", "\\d.i.r\\d.i.r2/", ".name- with extension", ".R"],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\...filename....ext", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "...filename...", ".ext"],
    ["name.and.ext", undefined, "name.and", ".ext"],
    // // no extensoion
    ["only name", undefined, "only name", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\name-without extension", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "name-without extension", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\foo", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "foo", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\.name-without extension", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", ".name-without extension", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\.", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", ".", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\..", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "..", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\...", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "...", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\.gitignore", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", ".gitignore", ""],
    ["C:\\dir1\\dir2\\...only-filename...", "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\", "...only-filename...", ""],
];


// -----------------------------------------

const isBrowser = typeof document === 'object';
const sep = Symbol();
const mdRows = [];
mdRows.push(mdrow(['Full Path', 'Folder', 'Name', 'Ext.'], false));
mdRows.push(mdrow([sep, sep, sep, sep]));
let counter = {ok: 0, fail: 0};
for (const item of testItems) {
    const path = item[0];
    const match = rx.exec(path);
    if (!match) {
        testFailed(path, 'regex does not match the input!');
        counter.fail++;
        mdRows.push(row(path));
    } else {
        if (item[1] === match[1] && item[2] === match[2] && item[3] === match[3]) {
            //testOk(path, match);
            //console.log(match, item);
            counter.ok++;
            mdRows.push(mdrow([path, match[1], match[2], match[3]], true));
        } else {
            testFailed(path, 'not as expected', {match, item});
            counter.fail++;
        }
    }
}

if (counter.fail === 0) {
    let table = mdTable(mdRows);
    if (isBrowser) {
        document.body.innerHTML = `<xmp>${table}</xmp>`;
    } else {
        console.log(table);
    }
}
console.log(`Failed:${counter.fail}, Success:${counter.ok}`);




// ----------------
// helper functions
// ----------------




function testFailed(path, message, match) {
    console.error(path, 'failed!', message, match);
}

function testOk(path, match) {
    console.log(path, {path: match[1], name: match[2] || null, ext: match[3] || null});
}

/**
 * @param {string[]} cells
 * @param {boolean} isCode
 * @returns {*}
 */
function mdcells(cells, isCode) {
    return cells.map(function (x) {
        if (x === undefined) return ''; // 'undefined';
        if (x === null) return ''; // 'null';
        if (x === sep) return sep;
        if (x === false) return '';
        if (x === '') return ''; // 'empty-string';
        return isCode && !isBrowser ? `\`${x}\`` : x;
    });
}

function mdrow(cells, isCode) {
    return mdcells(cells, isCode);
}

function mdTable(mdRows) {
    const w = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (const mdRow of mdRows) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mdRow.length; i++) {
            const cell = mdRow[i];
            if (cell !== sep) w[i] = Math.max(w[i], cell.length);
        }
    }
    const lines = [];
    for (const mdRow of mdRows) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mdRow.length; i++) {
            const cell = mdRow[i];
            mdRow[i] = cell === sep ? ''.padEnd(w[i], '-') : cell.padEnd(w[i]);
        }
        const line = '| ' + mdRow.join(' | ') + ' |';
        lines.push(line);
    }
    return lines.join("\n");
}
```

###### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harold/x2crewn4/) Test Result

| Full Path | Folder | Name | Ext. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\foo.ext` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `foo` | `.ext` |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\foo.ext1.ext` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `foo.ext1` | `.ext` |
| `/dir1/dir2/foo.ext` | `/dir1/dir2/` | `foo` | `.ext` |
| `C:\special$chars\f2\f [oo].ext1.e-x-t` | `C:\special$chars\f2\` | `f [oo].ext1` | `.e-x-t` |
| `\d.i.r\d.i.r2/.name- with extension.R` | `\d.i.r\d.i.r2/` | `.name- with extension` | `.R` |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\...filename....ext` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `...filename...` | `.ext` |
| `name.ext` |  | `name` | `.ext` |
| `.only name leading period .name.ext` |  | `.only name leading period .name` | `.ext` |
| `name.and.ext` |  | `name.and` | `.ext` |
| `only name` |  | `only name` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\name-without extension` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `name-without extension` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\foo` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `foo` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` |  |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\.name-without extension` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `.name-without extension` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\.` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `.` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\..` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `..` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\...` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `...` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\.gitignore` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `.gitignore` |  |
| `C:\dir1\dir2\...only-filename...` | `C:\dir1\dir2\` | `...only-filename...` |  |

Comment: Test cases are good too.

Comment: Seems quite robust. However, if the filename has a leading period as part of its name, this regex treats the full name as a file extension with no name. These types of files exist, such as `.Rprofile` or `.gitignore`. I am not sure whether they should be treated as file extensions or filenames though - I am leaning towards the latter. If the second capture group is changed to `(\.?.*?)` it seems to work on all your test cases. Full regex: `^(.*[\\\/])?(\.?.*?)(\.[^.]*?|)$`

Comment: Extra test cases: `C:\folder1\folder2\.name-without extension`, `.only name leading period` `.name.ext`. Also, your regex also already handles periods in the directories correctly. See `C:\fol.d.er1\fo.lde.r2/.name- with extension.R`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight modification to Angelo's excellent answer that allows for spaces in the path, filename and extension as well as missing parts:

```
function parsePath (path) {
    var parts = (/(\w?\:?\\?[\w\-_ \\]*\\+)?([\w-_ ]+)?(\.[\w-_ ]+)?/gi).exec(path);
    return {
        path: parts[0] || "",
        folder: parts[1] || "",
        name: parts[2] || "",
        extension: parts[3] || "",
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer with:

- File name and directory space support
- Named capture group
- Gets unlimited file extensions (captures `file.tar.gz`, not just `file.tar`)
- *NIX and Win support

`^.+(\\|\/)(?<file_name>([^\\\/\n]+)(\.)?[^\n\.]+)$`

Explanation:

1. `^.+(\\|\/)` Gets anything up to the final `/` or `\` in a file path
2. `(?<file_name>` Begin named capture group
3. `([^\\\/\n]+)` get anything except for a newline or new file
4. `(\.)?[^\n\.]+` Not really needed but it works well for issues with odd characters in file names
5. `)$` End named capture group and end line

Note that if you're putting this in a string and you need to escape backslashes (such as with C) you'll be using this string:

`"^.+(\\\\|\/)(?<file_name>([^\\\/\n]+)(\.)?[^\n\.]+)$"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the file name with its extension, Regex should be as below:

`[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

works for

```
path/to/your/filename.some
path/to/your/filename.some.other
path\to\your\filename.some
path\to\your\filename.some.other
http://path/to/your/filename.some
http://path/to/your/filename.some.other
And so on
```

Which returns full file name with extension(eg: filename.some or filename.some.other)

---

If you want to return file name without the last extension Regex should be as below:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+(?=\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$)
```

Which returns full file name without last extension(eg: "filename" for "filename.some" and "filename.some" for "filename.some.other")

Answer (score 2):

try this

`[^\\]+$`

you can also add extension for specificity

`[^\\]+pdf$`

Answer (score 1):

Click the <kbd>Explain</kbd> button on these links shown <kbd>TEST</kbd> to see how they work.

---

This is specific to the `pdf` extension.

[<kbd>TEST</kbd>](https://regexr.com/4g8iv) `^.+\\([^.]+)\.pdf$`

---

This is specific to **any** extension, not just `pdf`.

[<kbd>TEST</kbd>](https://regexr.com/4g8j2) `^.+\\([^.]+)\.[^\.]+$`

---

`([^.]+)`
This is the `$1` capture group to extract the filename **without the extension**.

---

`\\my-local-server\path\to\this_file may_contain-any&character.pdf`

will return

`this_file may_contain-any&character`

Comment: Both fail on filenames with multiple dots and on filenames without an extension.

Comment: And on files without a path.

Comment: Quit trolling along all the comments. This answers the OPs question.

Comment: You are correct. I'm sorry if I offended you or anyone else. Many answers here solve the OPs question. My problem is actually with the question and not with the answers. Most of the answers are probably correct according to the question, which is vague. I am new and I should have acted differently. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

**Direct approach:**

To answer your question as it's written, this will provide the most exact match:

```
^\\\\my-local-server\\path\\to\\(.+)\.pdf$
```

**General approach:**

This regex is short and simple, matches any filename in any folder (with or without extension) on both windows and *NIX:

```
.*[\\/]([^.]+)
```

If a file has multiple dots in its name, the above regex will capture the filename up to the first dot. This can easily be modified to match until the last dot if you know that you will not have files without extensions or that you will not have a path with dots in it.

If you know that the folder will only contain .pdf files or you are only interested in .pdf files and also know that the extension will never be misspelled, I would use this regex:

```
.*[\\/](.+)\.pdf$
```

**Explanation:**

- `.` matches anything except line terminators.
- `*` repeats the previous match from **zero** to as many times as possible.
- `[\\/]` matches a the last backslash or forward slash (previous ones are consumed by `.*`). It is possible to omit either the backslash or the forward slash if you know that only one type of environment will be used.
  If you want to capture the path, surround `.*` or `.*[\\/]` in parenthesis.
- Parenthesis will capture what is matched inside them.
- `[^.]` matches anything that is not a literal dot.
- `+` repeats the previous match **one** or more times, as many as possible.
- `\.` matches a literal dot.
- `pdf` matches the string pdf.
- `$` asserts the end of the string.

If you want to match files with zero, one or multiple dots in their names placed in a variable path which also may contain dots, it will start to get ugly. I have not provided an answer for this scenario as I think it is unlikely.

**Edit:** To also capture filenames without a path, replace the first part with `(?:.*[\\/])?`, which is an optional non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that works on windows/unix:

`"^(([A-Z]:)?[\.]?[\\{1,2}/]?.*[\\{1,2}/])*(.+)\.(.+)"`

First block: path 
Second block: dummy 
Third block: file name 
Fourth block: extension

Tested on:

```
".\var\www\www.example.com\index.php"
"\var\www\www.example.com\index.php"
"/var/www/www.example.com/index.php"
"./var/www/www.example.com/index.php"
"C:/var/www/www.example.com/index.php"
"D:/var/www/www.example.com/index.php"
"D:\\var\\www\\www.example.com\\index.php"
"\index.php"
"./index.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression extract the file extension, if group 3 isn't null it's the extension.

```
.*\\(.*\.(.+)|.*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

also one more for file in dir and root

```
   ^(.*\\)?(.*)(\..*)$
```

for file in dir

```
Full match  0-17    `\path\to\file.ext`
Group 1.    0-9 `\path\to\`
Group 2.    9-13    `file`
Group 3.    13-17   `.ext`
```

for file in root

```
Full match  0-8 `file.ext`
Group 2.    0-4 `file`
Group 3.    4-8 `.ext`
```

Answer (score 0):

For most of the cases ( that is some win , unx path , separator , bare file name , dot , file extension ) the following one is enough:

```
 // grap the dir part (1), the dir sep(2) , the bare file name (3) 
 path.replaceAll("""^(.*)[\\|\/](.*)([.]{1}.*)""","$3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work...

```
.*\/(.+)$
```

Posting here so I can get feedback

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution to extract the file name without the dot of the extension.
I begin with the answer from @Hammad Khan and add the dot in the search character. So, dots can be part of the file name:

```
[ \w-.]+\.
```

Then use the regex look ahead`(?= )` for a dot, so it will stop the search at the last dot (the dot before the extension), and the dot will not appears in the result:

```
[ \w-.]+(?=[.])
```

reorder, it's not necessary but look better:

```
[\w-. ]+(?=[.])
```