# How to retrieve all parts of path-like string using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example I have a path of the following format:

```
f1/f2/f3/aaa
```

I would like to have matching groups to return something like this:

```
["f1", "f2", "f3", "aaa"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this:

```
var str = "f1/f2/f3/aaa",
    arr = str.split('/');
console.log(arr);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DQn5M/).

This gets you a *real* array at the end, whereas with regular expressions, *at best*, you'd end up with an array-like string. Which seems somewhat pointless.

If you must use a regular-expression approach:

```
var str = "f1/f2/f3/aaa",
    arr = str.match(/(\w+)/g);
console.log(arr)​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DQn5M/1/).

And just look how much less comprehensible that is. Also how fragile it is (since, with that approach, it requires the separator to be a non-alphanumeric (or `_`) character). There really is, in *this* instance, no good reason to use regular expressions.

Comment: `/([^\/]+)/g` might make a better regex...just saying.  :)  But yeah, still not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @cHao: agreed but in the case of selecting all characters that *don't* match a `/` character? I'm *completely* sticking with the `split('/')` approach. Mainly due to my principle of refusing to over-complicate. =)