# Regular expression to extract part of a file path using the logstash grok filter

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am new to regular expressions but I think people here may give me valuable inputs. I am using the logstash [`grok`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.0.17/filters/grok) filter in which I can supply only regular expressions.

I have a string like this

```
/app/webpf04/sns882A/snsdomain/logs/access.log
```

I want to use a regular expression to get the `sns882A` part from the string, which is the substring after the third "/", how can I do that?

I am restricted to regex as grok only accepts regex. Is it possible to use regex for this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can use regular expression to get what you want via grok:

```
/[^/]+/[^/]+/(?<field1>[^/]+)/
```

Comment: I know this answer is way too late, but +1 anyway for being the first *correct* answer That is, a standalone regex (no other code and no delimiters) that uses named capture for the parts it's supposed to extract.

Answer (score 2):

for your regex:

```
    /\w*\/\w*\/(\w*)\/
```

You can also test with:
http://www.regextester.com/

By googling regex tester, you can have different UI.

Comment: From http://www.regextester.com/ it gives me no match, I tried http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ no result there as well...

Comment: This solution relies on directory and file names always consisting of alphanumeric characters or underscores. In particular there may be no spaces anywhere in the path

Comment: the match is index 0 based. You can also see: 1: (sns882A), which means its the first match.

Comment: When using /\w*\/\w*\/(\w*)\/ for grok filter, got grok parse failure error maybe because no match found.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in Perl:

```
my ($name) = ($fullname =~ m{^(?:/.*?){2}/(.*?)/});
```

**EDIT**:
If your framework does not support Perl-ish non-grouping groups `(?:xyz)`, this regex should work instead:

```
^/.*?/.*?/(.*?)/
```

If you are concerned about performance of `.*?`, this works as well:

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
```

**One more note:** All of regexes above will match string `/app/webpf04/sns882A/`.

But matching string is completely different from first matching group, which is `sns882A` in all three cases.

Comment: When I try ^(?:/.*?){2}/(.*?)/ part on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, it matched to /app/webpf04/sns882A/

Comment: You should use `(?:/[^/]*)`. Otherwise your regex may take a *long* time to decide that it doesn't match

Comment: This is exactly why I used `.*?` - to avoid greedy match, which can be very slow

Comment: Confirmed when I give ^(?:/.*?){2}/(.*?)/ to grok filter, I got the /app/webpf04/sns882A/ part of the string

Comment: Note that matching string is not the same as first matching group. See my amended answer

Comment: OP didn't ask for Perl

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using Perl then you should use the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $path = '/app/webpf04/sns882A/snsdomain/logs/access.log';
my @path = File::Spec->splitdir($path);

print $path[3], "\n";
```

**output**

```
sns882A
```

Comment: I can not use any languages, this is part of the logstash-grok configuration in which I can only supply expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer but a small bug fix. If you doesnt specify ^ in starting,it will go for the next match(try longer paths adding more / for input.). To fix it just add ^ in the starting like this. ^ means starting of the input line. finally group1 is your answer.

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
```

If you are using any URI paths use below.(it will handle path aswell as URI).

```
^.*?/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
```