# Mocking depends for directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that starts like

```
angular.module('App')
  .directive('pong', function ($window) {
```

How would I then mock `$window` in a test? I was thinking some like this but wasn't sure where to pass the mocked $window.

```
// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.testValue = null;
  $window = $injector.get('$window');
}));

function compileDirective(tpl) {
  if (!tpl) {
    tpl = '<button pong="{{testValue}}">Test</button>';
  }

  inject(function($compile) {
    element = $compile(tpl)(scope);
  });

  scope.$digest();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide mocked value like (you must to put this declaration before inject method calls)

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', mockWindow);
  });
});
```

then you have to create some spies on mockWindow object - as You expect that some method from $window will be called.

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694691/2956716, you need to override the service's provider.

For example, (I haven't tested this!)

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.provider('$window', $window); 
}));
```

where $window is the variable where you have injected the $window before.