# Testing Angular Directive with Dependencies like $location and $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

Thie question is somewhat related to [How do I inject a mock dependency into an angular directive with Jasmine on Karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694690/how-do-i-inject-a-mock-dependency-into-an-angular-directive-with-jasmine-on-karm). But I cant figure it out. Heres the thing:

I have a simple angular directive for rendering a head-part of my apllication with several parameters. One is passed, two came from the URL vie $location and $routeParam. The directive looks like this:

```
    'use strict';
myApp.directive('appHeader', ['$routeParams', '$location', function ($routeParams, $location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/partials/template.html',
        scope: {
            icon: '@icon'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var lastUrlPart = $location.path().split('/').pop();
            scope.project = $routeParams.itemName;
            scope.context = lastUrlPart === scope.project ? '' : lastUrlPart;
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is called via `<app-header icon="bullhorn"></app-header>`.

Now I want to add some tests. As for the template rendering I'm done. The following works like expected. The test passes.

```
describe('appHeader', function () {
    var element, scope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(module('myAppPartials'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        element = angular.element('<app-header icon="foo"></app-header>');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should contain the glyphicon passed to the directive', function () {
        expect(element.find('h1').find('.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-foo')).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Now I want to test that scope.context and scope.project are set accordingly to the dependencies $location and $routeParams, which I want to mock of course. How can I acieve this.

I tried for instance the answer from the question linked above:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.provider('$routeParams', function () {
            this.$get = function () {
                return {
                    itemName: 'foo'
                };
            };
        });
    }));
```

But In my test

```
it('should set scope.project to itemName from $routeParams', function () {
        expect(scope.project).toEqual('foo');
});
```

`scope.project` is undefined:

```
Running "karma:unit:run" (karma) task
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.3) appHeader should set scope.project to itemName from routeParams FAILED
        Expected undefined to equal 'foo'.
        Error: Expected undefined to equal 'foo'.
```

As for the location dependency I tried to setUp a Mock mysel like this:

```
var LocationMock = function (initialPath) {
            var pathStr = initialPath || '/project/bar';
            this.path = function (pathArg) {
                return pathArg ? pathStr = pathArg : pathStr;
            };
        };
```

Then injection $location in the before each and set a spyOn to the calling of path() like this:

```
spyOn(location, 'path').andCallFake(new LocationMock().path);
```

But then, scope.context is undefined, too.

```
it('should set scope.context to last part of URL', function () {
    expect(scope.context).toEqual('bar');
});
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider's mock works fine, but the problem is in scopes. Your directive has isolated scope. Thus this directive's scope is the child of the scope defined in test. Quick but not recomended fix is:

```
it('should set scope.project to itemName from $routeParams', function () {
    expect(scope.$$childHead.project).toEqual('foo'); });
```

Try to avoid use scope when testing directives. Better approach will be to mock template and check data in it. For your case it will be something like this:

```
    var viewTemplate = '<div>' +
        '<div id="project">{{project}}</div>' +
    '</div>';

    beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('path/to/partials/template.html', viewTemplate);
    }));
```

and test:

```
    it('should set scope.project to itemName from $routeParams', function () {
        expect(element.find('#project').text()).toEqual('foo');
    });
```

for the context it will be the same.

Comment: Thank you, that helped alot. I was too much thinking in controller context when it comes to scope in directives. Meanwhile I already figured that in the element every instance of context and project was filled like expected.