# Regex for complete string after autovue.classpath= in text file

Tags: c#, regex

I have following text in my file

> autovue.bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\AV\bin\
>
> autovue.classpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\AV\bin\jvue.jar;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\AV\bin\jvueserver.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jsonrpc4j.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\log4j-api.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jackson.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\stax2-api-4.2.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\woodstox-core-5.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\log4j-core.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\log4j-web.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jackson.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\stax2-api-4.2.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\woodstox-core-5.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jogl.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\SmartMarkupListener.jar autovue.jre=C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\jre\bin\java.exe

I need to get value of autovue.classpath means string after autovue.classpath="..." to the white spaces (i.e.)next line.

I tried with

```
MatchCollection matched=Regex.Matches(contents,@"classpath=\s*")

&

MatchCollection matched=Regex.Matches(contents,@"classpath=[A-Za-z-0-9]\w+")
```

but not getting expected.

Which should be the Regex for this in C# language.

Expected result:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\AV\bin\jvue.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jvueserver.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jsonrpc4j.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\log4j-api.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jackson.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\stax2-api-4.2.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\woodstox-core-5.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\log4j-core.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\log4j-web.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jackson.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\stax2-api-4.2.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\woodstox-core-5.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\jogl.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AV\bin\SmartMarkupListener.jar

Comment: I recommend reading one line at a time with streamreader.  You have a multiline text input and in multiline mode you will the return at the end of the line with regex has a different meaning.  You matches will get everything after the "classpath" and not just the one line.

Comment: Is this an INI file? Maybe you could use something like [ini-parser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/) if so. Regex is probably not the way to go unless this absolutely cannot be done another way.

Comment: Please can you provide the string you'd like as a result of the match?

Comment: @silleknarf i have updated the question and added expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(contents, @"(?<=autovue.classpath=)[^\r\n]+");
```

Explanation:

`(?<=autovue.classpath=)` is a positive look-behind for the text `autovue.classpath=`. This is not included in the match result.

`[^\r\n]+` then matches any number of characters that is not a carriage return or new line, to include in the match.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. it's working fine. I also need to get [jvue.jar;jvueserver.jar;....SmartMarkupListener.jar ] from the obtain result. Cloud you please tell me the regex for same ?

Comment: @stackoverflow so you want to split the match into an array, separated by the semicolons?

Comment: yes @johnathan some thing like "MatchCollection matchedAuthorsClasspath1 = Regex.Matches(contents, @"(?<=autovue.classpath=)[^;]+");"  but it's not working

Comment: You could always just do `match.Value.Split(';')` on the existing expression.

Comment: i am doing  String[] s2 = new String[20];
            string srt1 = match.ToString();
            int count = srt1.Split(';').Length - 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
               s2[i]= match.Value.Split(';').ToString();
            }  but it's return noting, am i doing right ?

Comment: I just need [jvue.jar;jvueserver.jar;....SmartMarkupListener.jar ]  file name only not complete path.

Comment: Try [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8). So `var fileNames = match.Value.Split(';').Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path));`

Comment: Thanks for your ans. but i am looking for file name only not complete path eg. if value of filePaths[0] is "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AV\\bin\\jvue.jar" then i want jvue.jar only

Comment: i don't want to use Linq. can you please suggest regex for input "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AV\\bin\\jvue.jar" to get jvue.jar as result

Comment: Maybe try this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367263/8126362

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text only between `autovue.classpath` and next semicolon (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\AV\bin\jvue.jar`, then:

```
MatchCollection matched = Regex.Matches(contents, @"(?<=autovue\.classpath=).+?(?=;)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"autovue.classpath=(.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

will find the text between `autovue.classpath=` and the end of the line. You can access it at `match.Groups[1]`.