# Angular get filename without extension from full path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am using angular and in my .ts file I want to get the filename of a path path without the extension.

So here is the full path + filename:

```
const fullpath = ["C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\the_filename.txt"]
```

I've been trying this:

```
getFileNameOnly() {
  var fileName = "C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\the_filename.txt";
  var res = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); 
  console.log(res);
}
```

This above returns error:

```
TypeError: fileName.substr is not a function
```

How can I do this so that the result is:

`"the_filename"` ?

Comment: What is `data` then? I bet it's not a string, or you've forgotten to the filename to as an argument to the function.

Comment: Sorry, updated question

Comment: Check some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363145/regex-for-extracting-filename-from-path) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

Comment: Well, the code you have most definitely works. Just copy and paste it into your console and you won't get any errors.

Comment: OK, tried with the console and it's returning .txt (the extension) not the filename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fullpath = "C:/Users/my.user/Desktop/the_filename.txt";
var filename = fullpath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
```

result :-
"the_filename"

Edit 1 :

```
var fullpath = "C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\the_filename.txt";
JSON.stringify(fullpath).split('\\').pop().split('.')[0]
```

result :-
"the_filename"

console image :
[image]

Comment: My path has backslash and when I change your code to have backslash it won't work

Comment: Does it work with "C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\my_file.txt" (instead of "the_filename.txt")?

Answer (score 1):

I've corrected your string ("\" has to be "\\" in a string, or it will "escape" u, m, d, ...) and the code:

```
getFileNameOnly() {
  var fileName = "C:\\Users\\my.user\\Desktop\\the_filename.txt";
  var res = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
  res = res.substr(0, res.lastIndexOf('.'));  
  console.log(res);
}
```

And with the table element:

```
getFileNameOnly() {
  const fullpath = ["C:\\Users\\my.user\\Desktop\\the_filename.txt"];
  var res = fileName[0].substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
  res = res.substr(0, res.lastIndexOf('.'));  
  console.log(res);
}
```

Note that you still need the double-backslash, it's a string.

Comment: The path is given to me in a variable a does not have double backslash only single backslash

Comment: If you console.log your variable (try it!), you'll have: "C:Usersmy.userDesktop he_filename.txt ". You should tell the person who provide this data that it is wrong formatted.

Comment: Console shows it like this: ["C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\the_filename.txt"]

Comment: Look in a minimal Typescript Playground example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAZglgNgUwHIgLYIgXggIgMIBcAOgKoDOCYZRqAngHQCuFYRAIgmQNYAuA9gAciPABYIA+rEQA7NAno8AHjxwBuAFABjPtLJ9E9OHwDmACinI5ASlVA

Comment: OK sorry about this: I missed the [] ... I'm getting the variable like this: var fileName = ["C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\the_filename.txt"];

Comment: I've updated my code, but you still need the double-backslash if you hard-code the file path (because, for example, \t is a tab in a string).

Answer (score 0):

use it this way

```
 getFileNameOnly() {
  var fileName = "C:\\Users\\my.user\\Desktop\\the_filename.txt";
  var res = fileName.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop(); 
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: OK sorry about this: I missed the [] ... I'm getting the variable like this: var fileName = ["C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\the_filename.txt"];