# I want to get filename from different server and store in a variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to get the file name from different server and store it in a variable.

example:
from 1 server I want to get the file name using below command

```
FILE_NAME=$(ssh user@host ls /acd/file/zipped/processing/trigger/Daily_trigger_$DATE*.csv*)
```

but `FILE_NAME` stores complete path and filename:

```
/acd/file/zipped/processing/trigger/Daily_trigger_19072021_220305.csv
```

I only want the filename.

Comment: if you are receiving the whole path, you can try using regex in order to get only the characters at the end for the filename, like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363145/regex-for-extracting-filename-from-path

Comment: Assuming your glob always returns exactly one file: `FILE_NAME=$(ssh user@host basename /acd/file/zipped/processing/trigger/Daily_trigger_$DATE*.csv*)`

Comment: thanks jhnc for the suggestion, the basename worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has `basename`, you can use it, as in jhnc's comment, above.

If you want a pure bash solution, you can use

`${FILE_NAME##*/}`

to get only the filename part. See [Shell Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual for more.