# How to remove folder names from a file path using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Example:
c:/users/images/logo.png to logo.png
c:\users\images\logo.png to logo.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for extracting filename from path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363145/regex-for-extracting-filename-from-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
```

try above this may help to get file name from any path this will support / OR \ both

Comment: This is an **obvious** duplicate question. Please don't post answers to obvious duplicates.